# short date range for selected date checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime

We have set of checkbox which is identified as date checkbox. These are known as check-in date. Check-out is 1 greater then check-in date. For example if check-in date is 24/09/2017 then checkout is 25/09/2017.

So We are trying to get short date range if continuous date selected, For example, if we have four date 24/09/2017,25/09/2017,26/09/2017,27/09/2017. If we select  24/09/2017 then check-in date is 24/09/2017 and checkout is 25/09/2017. But if we select 24 and 25,26 then in array we have three values

```
checkindat:"24/09/2017",checkouts:"25/09/2017"
```

and

```
checkindat:"25/09/2017",checkouts:"26/09/2017"
```

and

```
checkindat:"26/09/2017",checkouts:"27/09/2017"
```

so we want if date range in sequence then it would show check-in date as 24/0/2017 and checkout date as 27/09/2017. But if we un-check date then it would work as its working now.

here is some part of my code in this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mb4d362m/2/)**

```js
var alreadycheckin = [];

$("input[class='check htcheck']:checkbox").change(function() {
  var roomids = $(this).attr("roomid");
  checkindat = $(this).attr("name");
  var new_dates = moment(checkindat, "DD.MM.YYYY");
  var checkid = new_dates.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  //if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
  {
    var html = '';
    arr = [];
    var roomcods = $(this).attr("value");
    var roomids = $(this).attr("roomid");
    checkindat = $(this).attr("name");
    var new_dates = moment(checkindat, "DD.MM.YYYY");

    var checkid = new_dates.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    //console.log(checkid);
    var checkouts = new_dates.add(1, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    var roomcodes = $(this).attr("value");
    var uniq = roomids + '_' + name + '_' + checkindat;
    uniq = uniq.split("/").join("").split("_").join("");
    var uniqs = '';
    //console.log($("#aa"+roomids));
    // alreadycheckin.push({ roomids : roomids, checkindat : checkindat, checkouts: checkouts });
    var arrElement = {
      roomids: roomids,
      checkindat: checkindat,
      checkouts: checkouts
    };
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //alreadycheckin[uniq]={ roomids : roomids, checkindat : checkindat, checkouts: checkouts };
      alreadycheckin.push(arrElement);
    } else {
      var index1 = arr.indexOf(arrElement);
      alreadycheckin.splice(index1, 1);
    }

    var tmpAlreadycheckin = [];
    // tmpAlreadycheckin=alreadycheckin.slice(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < alreadycheckin.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        if (typeof alreadycheckin[i - 1] != "undefined" || alreadycheckin[i - 1] != null) {
          if (alreadycheckin[i].checkouts == alreadycheckin[i - 1].checkindat) {
            console.log("111");
            var arrElement1 = {
              roomids: roomids,
              checkindat: alreadycheckin[i].checkindat,
              checkouts: alreadycheckin[i - 1].checkouts
            };
            tmpAlreadycheckin.push(arrElement1);
            //tmpAlreadycheckin[i].checkouts =tmpAlreadycheckin[i+1].checkouts;
            //tmpAlreadycheckin.splice(i+1, 1);
          } else {
            console.log("2222");
            var arrElement2 = {
              roomids: roomids,
              checkindat: alreadycheckin[i].checkindat,
              checkouts: alreadycheckin[i].checkouts
            };
            tmpAlreadycheckin.push(arrElement2);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("3333");
          var arrElement2 = {
            roomids: roomids,
            checkindat: alreadycheckin[i].checkindat,
            checkouts: alreadycheckin[i].checkouts
          };
          tmpAlreadycheckin.push(arrElement2);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("3333");
        var arrElement2 = {
          roomids: roomids,
          checkindat: alreadycheckin[i].checkindat,
          checkouts: alreadycheckin[i].checkouts
        };
        tmpAlreadycheckin.push(arrElement2);
      }


    }
    console.log(tmpAlreadycheckin);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input roomid="15" id="15_24/09/2017" class="check htcheck" name="24/09/2017" value="1" type="checkbox">24/09/2017 <br/>
<input roomid="15" id="15_25/09/2017" class="check htcheck" name="25/09/2017" value="1" type="checkbox">25/09/2017 <br/>
<input roomid="15" id="15_26/09/2017" class="check htcheck" name="26/09/2017" value="1" type="checkbox">26/09/2017 <br/>
<input roomid="15" id="15_27/09/2017" class="check htcheck" name="27/09/2017" value="1" type="checkbox">27/09/2017 <br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of objects in this format: `[{checkindat:"24/09/2017",checkouts:"25/09/2017"},{checkindat:"25/09/2017",checkouts:"26/09/2017"}]` :then you could first sort the array by checkindate, and then iterate over the array *backwards*. You would start on the last element, look at its `checkindat`, then compare it to the previous element's `checkouts`. If they're the same, update the previous elements `checkouts` to the one ahead of it, and then delete the one ahead of it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I did, its working fine for 2 dates, But for 3 dates its not working correctly.

Comment: Can you post some simplified example code to show me? Make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mb4d362m/3/  Please check this. i removed some of the code, which is not necessary .

Comment: Thank you for that. When you make the `tmpAlreadycheckin`, you didn't sort it by checkin date first, so it breaks depending on the order you click the buttons. You must sort before processing.

Comment: @pankajagarwal I would recommend rebuilding your `arrElement` object for every checkbox every time a checkbox is clicked, rather than persisting them. I think that might be the cause of your issues.

Comment: @pankajagarwal I said the above because in your `//doing calculations` area, you **change** the objects that are in the `alreadycheckin` array, but without changing the contents of the list. Another option is to do a deep copy instead of `tmpAlreadycheckin=alreadycheckin.slice(0);`, where you don't use the same objects as the ones that are in `alreadycheckin`. That would also fix it.

Comment: I created deep copy of array but still not working correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/mb4d362m/8/

Comment: no, that's not a deep copy. Sorry. That's just a shallow copy with more characters.

Comment: Ohhh sorry, Thanks for the info. Didn't know we can clone like this also. 
But still not working correctly. Suppose you checked 24,25 and 26, Then you unselect  25, then it would show check-in:25,check-out:25 and check-in:26,check-out:27

Comment: Yes, I believe that's partially because you still aren't *sorting* the array.

Comment: after you populate `tmpAlreadycheckin`, write a sort function, `tmpAlreadycheckin.sort()`, so that it sorts by checkindat. Unfortunately you probably won't be able to just sort by string because the date string is not in international format, so you may have to convert it to a date to sort it properly.

Comment: can you link to the jsfiddle? @Mangita

Comment: Hi, Implemented sorting by checkindat, But still not working. you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/mb4d362m/10/

Comment: it doesn't look to me like it's actually sorting the array correctly.

Comment: That's because you're calling new Date(a.checkindat) and it's not recognizing the date

Comment: Hi, Got the problem. problem is its not poping correct elements on un-check. i think now its working correctly. Thanks for your great help @TKoL here is working solution https://jsfiddle.net/mb4d362m/27/ please check.

Comment: @pankajagarwal awesome. Will you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Yes, Sure. You helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @TKoL Hi Its working for me only problem is that when we select 30/09/2017 and 01/10/2017,  in this case its not working correctly